# Get id of a record with the lowest sequence

Tags: search, odoo, odoo-8

I have this class

```
name = fields.Char("Name")
sequence = fields.Integer("Sequence")
description = fields.Text("Description")
```

I need a search method to find the id with lower sequence

Comment: I dont understand it.

Comment: in a method I need the ID for the "register" with the lower sequence

Comment: Here the `sequence  = fields.Integer("Sequence")` .. Is the sequence array ?.

Comment: for example state_id = self.env['ags.traffic.operation.state'].search([]).get('id') not work state_id = self.env['ags.traffic.operation.state'].search([]).id not work state_id = self.env['ags.traffic.operation.state'].search(['name','=','Gone']) not work

Comment: `class transport_traffic_state_type(models.Model):
    _name = "ags.traffic.operation.state"
    _order = 'sequence asc'

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    sequence = fields.Integer("Sequence")
    description = fields.Text("Description")
    state_type = fields.Selection(
        [('beginning', 'Beginning'), ('notification', 'Notification'),
         ('ending', 'Ending')], 'Type')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = self.env['your.model'].search([], limit=1, order='sequence desc')
```

should to the trick

Comment: In the end i change "asc" for "desc", but it is i wanted, Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I think this search function would do the trick.

```
def _find_register(self, operator, value):
    lowest_sequence_id = False
    lowest_sequence = False
    for state in self.env['ags.traffic.operation.state'].search([('id','>',0)]):
        if not lowest_sequence:
            lowest_sequence_id = state.id
            lowest_sequence = state.sequence
        elif state.sequence < lowest_sequence:
            lowest_sequence = state.sequence
    return [('id', '=', lowest_sequence_id)]
```